# Pressing back button exits the app instead of navigating to the previous screen while using navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the navigation architecture component in my app and whenever I navigate to a screen and then try to return to the previous screen using the back button, instead of navigating back the app exits.

My **Navigation Graph** looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
    app:startDestination="@id/authFragment">

    <fragment
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_screen"
        android:id="@+id/sellerListScreenFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.SellerMainScreenFragment"
        android:label="SellerListScreenFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sellerListScreenFragment_to_creditFragment"
            app:destination="@id/credit_nav_graph" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.AuthFragment"
        android:label="AuthFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_auth" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_authFragment_to_sellerListScreenFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sellerListScreenFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <navigation android:id="@+id/credit_nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/creditFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/creditAddFragment"
            android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.CreditAddFragment"
            android:label="CreditAddFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_credit_add">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_creditAddFragment_self"
                app:destination="@id/creditAddFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_creditAddFragment_to_transactionResultFragment"
                app:destination="@id/transactionResultFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/transactionResultFragment"
            android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.TransactionResultFragment"
            android:label="TransactionResultFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transaction_result">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_transactionResultFragment_self"
                app:destination="@id/transactionResultFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/creditFragment"
            android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.CreditFragment"
            android:label="CreditFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_credit_enter_no">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_creditFragment_to_creditAddFragment"
                app:destination="@id/creditAddFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_creditFragment_self"
                app:destination="@id/creditFragment" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
    <action android:id="@+id/action_global_sellerListScreenFragment" app:destination="@id/sellerListScreenFragment"/>
</navigation>
```

I've tried to fix this using a custom `onBackPressedDispatcher` callback, but on top of leading to some strange behaviour it is also tedious to do it for every fragment and seems to be too much work for something that should be handled by the navigation component.

So is there a way to fix this problem as I have gone through my code but there doesn't seem to be anything that influences the navigation behaviour yet it doesn't work as intended.

Thanks for helping out!

**Edit :-**

As asked, I am providing the setup using which I navigate from , for example, `SellerMainScreenFragment` to `CreditFragment`

```kotlin
binding.fabCredit.setOnClickListener {        
    findNavController().
        navigate(R.id.action_sellerListScreenFragment_to_creditFragment)
}
```

Here I use a *FAB* to navigate from `SellerMainScreenFragment` to `CreditFragment`.

But after navigating to `CreditFragment`, on pressing the back button the app just exits instead of navigating back.

Comment: Check [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-similar-back-stack-like-instagram-youtube-and-more-cf299a617492)

Comment: Post your setup and how you navigate to this destination

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have edited the question as you had asked, hope it provides some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `app:defaultNavHost="true"` to the `NavHostFragment` in your main `Activity` layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

From the documentation:

> The `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute ensures that your `NavHostFragment` intercepts the system Back button. Note that only one `NavHost` can be the default. If you have multiple hosts in the same layout (two-pane layouts, for example), be sure to specify only one default `NavHost`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Thank you so much. That was indeed the thing that I had missed. I had almost given up on having proper navigation, but thanks to you, I was able to get it to work. I can't believe I had given up on the problem due to such a dumb thing on my part. All that aside, if I may bother you once more, the back button is working properly in the global navigation graph, but in the nested graph, pressing back does nothing. So if there is something I am missing again, can you just point it out once more. Again, extremely thankful for your help.

Comment: It's hard to tell. I would suggest asking another question about this specific issue.

Comment: Okay, I see. I think I'll try to fix it. If unable to solve it, I will go ahead and ask another question.